# Create synonym for function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, sql-server-2017, synonym

Would you prompt me, please, how to create synonym for function in SQL Server?

```
This method: CREATE SYNONYM cDateMin FOR server.db.[dbo].cDateMin
```

Doesn't help.

Script:

```
select dbo.cDateMin()
```

leads to the error:

```
Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.cDateMin", or the name is ambiguous.
```

Script:

```
select cDateMin()
```

leads to the error:

```
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 9
'cDateMin' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

Script:

```
select dbo.cDateMin
```

leads to the error:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The multi-part identifier "dbo.cDateMin" could not be bound.
```

Script:

```
select cDateMin
```

leads to the error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Invalid column name 'cDateMin'.
```

Guide from official source (to make a synonym by clicking the right button of the mouse on synonyms folder in SSMS ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/synonyms/create-synonyms?view=sql-server-ver15)) and creation the synonym 'by hand') created the same synonym and led tho the same errors.

Creation synonyms with the names different from the function name also didn't help.

Comment: From the [Official Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (which should always be your first port of call): **Four-part names for function base objects are not supported.**

Comment: @Dale K, thank you for your answer. The Official Docs (your link) says: Synonyms can be created for the following types of objects: Assembly (CLR) Scalar Function, Assembly (CLR) Table-valued Function. My functions are located in the Folders: Table-valued Functions and Scalar Valued Functions. How can I know: if they have four-part names?

Comment: This is a 4 part name `server.db.[dbo].cDateMin`, i.e. Server, Database, Schema, Object. As opposed to a 2 part name e.g. `[dbo].cDateMin`

Comment: "*How can I know: if they have four-part names*" - if your name contains three dots `.`

Comment: Thank you. It's interesting, if synonyms for functions are not allowed, why then, in the window of synonym creation it is possible to select 'Function' object type? I think, every time we create synonym, we should show four part names.

Comment: You only need 4 part naming for a linked server... which is exactly why you can't create a synonym. If its not a linked server, don't use 4 part naming.

Comment: @Dale K, linked server - is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.